# Can Daemon start external process with STDOUT?

Tags: c, linux, daemon

This is a Linux specific question.

When daemon application starts it usually closes its standard streams (STDOUT, STERR and STDIN).

My daemon application needs to start external application that may print messages to STDOUT that I need to capture.

It seems that this child application does not get STDOUT, because daemon does not have one.  What is the way to start the external app and to supply it its STDOUT in this environment?

Do I have to not close daemon STDOUT to get external application to run?

Comment: `When daemon application starts it usually closes its standard streams (STDOUT, STERR and STDIN).` I don't think so why do you think that ?

Comment: @Stargateur, I think they mean "redirected to /dev/null" (or a log file).

Comment: Re *My daemon application needs to start external application that may print messages to STDOUT that I need to capture.*", So what's the problem? The child's STDOUT and the parent's STDOUT are different handles

Comment: If what you want to do is capture the child process's stdout - would it be sufficient to create a pipe, then redirect the child process's stdout and stderr to the write end of that pipe (and have the parent read from the other end)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A daemon creates a child process via fork(); the child inherits all the file descriptors (that are not close-on-exec) from its parent.

If you want your daemon to receive stdout from the child, you need to point its file descriptor 1 (fileno(stdout)) to someplace the daemon can see it.  The easiest is a socket, but you could use a file as well.

Some code (that I haven't compiled, but is roughly correct and should get you well on your way):

```
// run the passed-in command in a process, returning a read file 
// descriptor that will read its stdout
static int
spawn (const char * const cmd)
{
    int comlink[2];
    pid_t pid;

    if (pipe(comlink)) {
        // handle error
    }
    if ((pid = fork()) == -1) {
        // handle error
    }
    if (pid == 0) {
        // the child
        if (dup2(comlink[1], fileno(stdout))) {
            // handle error
        }
        close(comlink[0]);
        close(comlink[1]);
        execl(...);  // get cmd into some exec format and put it here
        _exit(-1);   // should never be reached
    } else {
        // the parent
        close(comlink[1]);
        return comlink[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Daemon spawn?  :)

Comment: I'm intrigued that you think a socket is easiest -- which socket would you open and why?  I can see that it might be configured to use a socket, but I'd not regard it as particularly easy or obvious.

Comment: I'd open a socketpair via pipe() as in the spawn() func I gave above.  Since we have a parent/child relationship, it's a trivial way to maintain communication.  A side-benefit is that the parent can discover that the child has died in the normal select() loop, as the child's death results in the socket being closed.  It can make for cleaner code than catching the SIGCHLD as it can eliminate critical regions.

Comment: Hmmmm...I guess it's a terminology issue.  I don't regard pipes as sockets.  Maybe they're implemented as sockets these days (they weren't when I learned kernel internals) but ... I see that you are assuming that the daemon wants to see the output from the child process.  That's a legitimate possibility - not one I specifically considered.  I'm not sure how common it is, nor am I sure what should happen to the standard error of the child: a second pipe, or the same pipe?  But it all depends on what the child is supposed to do, which we don't know.

Comment: _[...time passes...]_ I see the daemon must capture the standard output of the child according to the question.  So using a pipe to capture that is reasonable.  What happens with standard error is still undefined, which is mildly careless.

Comment: Yup, I agree--it's not clear what the OP actually wants.  My read of his question was that he is using "daemon" to mean "process that creates other processes" and that's the sense I answered.

Comment: Well, it could be that the child will syslog() error information so stderr is unneeded and ought to go to /dev/null.  (Which I suppose could be useful if you want to be able to run the child directly for debugging and see its error output, though I agree that that's inelegant.  Definitely not the way I would code).